# Android apk file not opening pragmatically

Tags: android

i am trying to open an apk file in my app all other apps are opening fine by intents but apk file is not opening by 
this  my method to open file

```
public static void openFile(Activity activity, File file, String extension) {


    Log.i("mmmtttte", extension);
    String type = getMimeType(extension);
    if (type != null)
        Log.i("mmmtttt", type);


    ///Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);


    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);


    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (type != null && !type.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i("mmmtttte2", extension+":::::::"+type);

        pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, type);

    } else {
        Log.i("mmmtttte3", extension+":::::::"+type);

        pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "*/*");

    }
    pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        activity.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and these are my logs

```
02-28 01:09:35.790 3919-3919/com.****.**** I/mmmtttte: apk
02-28 01:09:35.790 3919-3919/com.****.**** I/mmmtttt: application/vnd.android.package-archive
02-28 01:09:35.790 3919-3919/com.****.**** I/mmmtttte2: apk:::::::application/vnd.android.package-archive
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.*****.**** W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.****.****.provider/root/storage/emulated/0/.v****_com.****.****/.hiddenFolder/Files/238021605.bin typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x4000001 }
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3951)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3912)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4235)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4203)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at com.****.****.FileUtilis.openFile(FileUtilis.java:1144)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at com.****.****.fragments.SecuredImagesScreen.openFile(SecuredImagesScreen.java:1355)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at com.****.****.fragments.SecuredImagesScreen.decryptAndOpenFile(SecuredImagesScreen.java:344)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.****.**** W/System.err:     at com.****.****.fragments.SecuredImagesScreen.onItemClick(SecuredImagesScreen.java:564)
02-28 01:09:35.793 3919-3919/com.********.**** W/System.err:     at com.****.****.adapters.SubRecyclerGalleryAdapter$5$1.run(SubRecyclerGalleryAdapter.java:426)
```

can someone help what is the issue please or what am i doing wrong this actually i am hiding files in my app by replacing extension .bin but all other files are opening except apk files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but as per your Log the error is regarding the intent. You intent fails to load as no activity is available to handle it as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html)

Check certain conditions before execution

- Check if permissions are mentioned in [manifest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) file.
- If it's a dangerous permission then permission has to be requested programmatically in [code](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) .
- Check whether you are requesting correct system flag with correct parameters from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) .
- List item

Hope it helps!